# error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'vector<T>::iterator' in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to learn the C++. I wrote this function template to print the vector and I got this ERROR.
Here's my code:

```cpp
// some vector features
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void printVector(vector<T> v)
{
    for (vector<T>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) // error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'vector<T>::iterator'
    // for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) // works when gives the type 'int'
    // for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) // works in c++11
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    // constructor

    vector<int> v1(10); //size 10, all elements are 0

    printVector<int> (v1);

}
```

```bash
> g++ codeName.cpp
error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'vector<T>::iterator'
    for(vector<T>::iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); it++)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        typename 
1 error generated.
```

I know it can be solved by algorithm `for_each`, and the `auto` type in c++11. I just don't understand why I can't use `T` over here and how to address this error.

Thanks.

Comment: It's easier than you think. Simply do exactly what the error message tells you to do (after reading the duplicate question).

Comment: This is exactly the type of situation that `auto` or `range-for` are meant to solve